# Python| reiterative addition of elements

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

For example, the molecular weight of water (H20) is: 2(1.00794) + 15.9994 = 18
Code:

```
formula = int(input("Enter the number of elements: "))
for i in range(formula):
    element = input("enter your element: ")
    molCount = float(input("enter the molecule count: "))
    print(molCount)
    atomWeight = float(input("enter the atomic weight: "))
    print(atomWeight)
    total = molCount*atomWeight
print(total)
total = total + total
print(total)
```

Need help on getting multiple elements added together...

Answer (score 0):

There's a mistake on the line: 
`total = molCount*atomWeight`

You probably meant `total += molCount*atomWeight` instead.

Comment: He also need to define total

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, define total before your for loop. Secondly, I think your equation needs to be

```
total += (molCount * atomWeight)
```

instead of the original. Edited code:

```
formula = int(input("Enter the number of elements: "))
total = 0
for i in range(formula):
    molCount = int(input("Enter the molecule count: "))
    print("Molecule count: " + str(molCount))
    atomWeight = float(input("Enter the atomic weight: "))
    print("Atomic Weight: " + str(atomWeight))
    total += (molCount * atomWeight)
print(total)
```

Comment: Hi Sam it didn't work. What I want to do is add the cumulative weight of all elements.
Example H20 
               H = 1.00794 (multiply by 2, for 2 hydrogen atoms)
               O = 15.9994 (only has 1 Oxygen atom)
1.00794(2) + 15.9994(1) 
= 18.01528

Comment: I edited the answer. I tested it, and it works. Hope this is what you need. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you Sam..this was a challenging for me.